# Refactor subscribe() to map()/flatMap() Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have this method and want to get rid of subscribe() (in line 5) and use map() or flatMap() instead (because it's not good to use subscribe() in a non-blocking scope):

```
private Mono<HttpStatus> transferToGlobalLibrary(UnpublishedArticle unpublishedArticle) {
    return updateArticleService.updateArticle(unpublishedToOutputContentAdapter.adaptUnpublishedArticle(unpublishedArticle))
                .map(httpStatusUpdateArticle -> {
                    if (httpStatusUpdateArticle.is2xxSuccessful())
                        articleRepository.save(unpublishedArticle).subscribe();
                    return httpStatusUpdateArticle;
                });
 }
```

I tried the following:

```
return updateArticleService.updateArticle(unpublishedToOutputContentAdapter.adaptUnpublishedArticle(unpublishedArticle))
                .map(httpStatusUpdateArticle -> {
                    if (httpStatusUpdateArticle.is2xxSuccessful())
                        return articleRepository.save(unpublishedArticle)
                                .flatMap(savedArticle -> httpStatusUpdateArticle);
                    return httpStatusUpdateArticle;
                });
```

which gives me the error *no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that HttpStatus conforms to Mono<? extends R>*. Why is this error displayed?

What is the best way to refactor the code? Thanks!

Notes:

- updateArticle() performs a REST API call, httpStatusUpdateArticle contains the resulting HttpStatus

Comment: the error is basically telling you that you are returning a `HttpStatus` when it wants `Mono<? extends R>` which is sort of saying, it wants you to return a `Mono`. when you use `Map` you need to return a concrete value. When you use `flatMap`you need to always return a `Mono`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` is a method that returns a `Mono`.

When you return `httpStatusUpdateArticle` it's a `Mono< HttpStatus>`.

`flatMap` also returns a `Mono`. So when you return `flatMap` inside `map`, then `map` returns a `Mono<Mono<HttpStatus>>`.

One solution is to not call `map` in the first place:

```
return updateArticleService.updateArticle(unpublishedToOutputContentAdapter.adaptUnpublishedArticle(unpublishedArticle))
            .flatMap(httpStatusUpdateArticle -> {
                if (httpStatusUpdateArticle.is2xxSuccessful())
                    return articleRepository.save(unpublishedArticle)
                                            .map(savedArticle -> httpStatusUpdateArticle);
                return Mono.just(httpStatusUpdateArticle);
            });
```